# Theoretical standard error when sampling from a single sample different results

Tags: r, standard-deviation, inference, standard-error

When researching the standard error of the mean I found a code block on this forum that looked like this:

```
# the size of a sample
n <- 100

# set true mean and standard deviation values
m <- 75
s <- 20

# now generate lots and lots of samples with mean m and standard deviation s
# and get the means of those samples. Save them in y.
y <- replicate( 10000, mean( rnorm(n, m, s) ) )

# point estimate
mean(y)

# standard deviation of those means
sd(y)

# calcuation of theoretical standard error
s / sqrt(n)
```

Sure enough, the last 2 lines of r code return very close numbers (2 Vs. 2.002).

The line that generates a variable `y` it looks like a new distribution is being generated each time with mean m and sd s.

```
y <- replicate( 10000, mean( rnorm(n, m, s) ) )
```

I was trying to understand why 10000 samples with the exact same sd and mean would be useful or relevant in real world analysis. I then thought that maybe the idea is that you have a hypothetical population with a given mean and sd e.g.

```
# random variable
random_var <- rnorm(1000000, m, s)
```

Then, I wanted to see if I took samples from this population could I infer the standard error in the same way as the block above:

```
# random variable sampling distribution
y2 <- replicate(10000, mean(sample(random_var, 1000, replace = F)))

# sd of these means
sd(y2)

# theoretical standard error
s / sqrt(n)
```

This time `sd(y2)` (~2.5) is quite different from `sd(y)` (~2).

Why? Would it not be expected that if drawing many samples from a normal distribution that I could calculate the theoretical standard error with `s / sqrt(n)`?

Comment: This question is predicated on misunderstanding how `rnorm` and `sample` work in `R`, so reading their help pages would be a good start. `rnorm` *never* returns two samples with the "exact same sd and mean."  It returns *random* samples and, by its very nature, their means and sds vary from one sample to another. In particular, your "hypothetical population" does not have mean `m` and sd `s` (although they will be close).  Moreover, by specifying `replace=FALSE` you are changing how you sample. Finally, you are not taking samples of size `n` (which is 100) but of size 1000!

Comment: @whuber assuming I had written correct r code and had more advanced understanding of those functions, would you expect to then be able to estimate the standard error by sampling from one single distribution ```random_var``` the same as using ```replicate( 10000, mean( rnorm(n, m, s) ) )```?

Comment: No--those are two different things.  `random_var` is a sample of a population, from which you proceed to resample.  The properties of the resamples will be properties of `random_var`, not of `rnorm`.  Although there is a predictable statistical relationship among them, the details of that relationship in any particular case can be determined only by computing the statistical properties of the numbers in the `random_var` array.